# How does intrinsic work?

Tags: css

I have never heard of this `intrinsic` value before until I come across **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Live_examples)** page on MDN.

From what I know **intrinsic** means *natural*. So how does this work out in CSS. I thought that `auto` would have been *natural*. I've searched around a bit but can't find anything on it.

What does it do different than `auto`?

The example I saw was `max-width: intrinsic;`

Comment: interestingly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width doesn't think it is a valid value...

Comment: yep, but Mozilla has `-moz-max-content`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the `intrinsic` value is part of the newer CSS3 sizing module:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/

I have not used it yet but perhaps the reference will provide you with more information.

Based on a quick review, this module would make it easier to specify how content fills the width and height of a parent containing block.

At the moment, JavaScript functions are often used to compute widths and heights of container blocks based on % values for variable child elements content.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see anywhere that says that `intrinsic` is a valid value. Plenty of uses of the word in the document but never as an actual value.

Comment: @Chris I think that `intrinsic` is experimental, hence not formally valid.

Comment: @MarcAudet: My point is that `intrinsic` isn't ever listed as a valid value for max-width, not even in that document. In the document things like `fill-available` and `max-content` are new values that use "intrinsic sizing" but the CSS as used in the example page isn't valid, even according to that. I suppose it might have been valid in an older draft maybe...

Comment: @Chris - See http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-box-20021024/#the-width which is the CSS3 box-model draft from 2002. It does not appear in later "official" drafts, but may have done in editor's drafts. In the latext version it seems to have been replaced by min-content, max-content and fit-content.

Answer (score 8):

It allows you to set the width of an element to stretch wide enough to accommodate its children. So, if a div element contained a wide image and some text, the div would stretch wide enough to accommodate the image, and the text would begin breaking at that threshold.

Definitely experimental and not widely supported: http://caniuse.com/intrinsic-width

Answer (score 4):

> Intrinsic sizing determines sizes **based on the contents of an element,
>   without regard for its context**.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#intrinsic-sizing

Comment: That page still suggests that it isn't actually a valid value though, just that there are new values that use an intrinsic sizing model.

Comment: @Chris It's not technically valid yet because it's not part of a final standard, just like HTML5

Comment: See my answer to Marc on another question. The value as used in the example is not a valid value according to that doc.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that in iOS8, flexbox children may not always try to contain all their children and instead max their height to the available viewport.
`min-height: min-intrinsic` fixes that problem.