# Maintain aspect ratio when page is resized or viewed on a different device

Tags: html, css

I’m working on a project and I want my webpage to maintain its style and aspect ratio anytime it is resized or viewed on any device. I have tried to use the position attribute (position:fixed;) on CSS but it’s not working.  How can this be done using CSS?

Comment: Aspect ratio of a webpage is not something you can set through some native property value -- it's inferred from your overall page layout. If you have a tall banner to the left of your main body text which is centered in the viewport and spans say, its height, then your aspect ratio is increased because of the banner to the left. Maintaining aspect ratio in your case is about maintaining your layout. A webpage is not a video frame in this regard.

Comment: its about intrinsic ratio. there is a well known hack.. with padding and absolut positioning: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video ...but there 'll be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294294/how-does-intrinsic-work

Comment: @amn, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @munomono, thanks for the explanation and the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
    figure {
    width: 36%;
    margin: 8px auto;
}
 
div.relative_div {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    position: relative;
    background: black;
}
 
div.relative_div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<figure>
    <div class="relative_div">
        <div>Relative Aspect Ratio </div>
    </div>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the CSS, all we have to do is nest an element with 100% width inside a “responsive” percentage-based-width parent element, and then declare a % for bottom or top padding based on the ratio we want to maintain. To calculate the percentage needed for any aspect ratio we can use the following formula:

B / (A / 100) = C%

So for 16:9 (where 16 is A and 9 is B):

9 / .16 = 56.25 (%)